# Flex Div not shrinking

Tags: css, flexbox

I wanted to shrink the `cta-content` text to the second line if two buttons are present in the `cta-wrapper`

I wanted to display `cta-content` in single line if only one button.

I tried to give width to `cta-content` but its shrinking both the div. Please suggest me if this can be done without Javascript & changing the HTML mock-up(HTML can be changed but it should be same for both)

[image: Scenario 1]
[image: Scenario 2]

```css
.cta-module {
  text-align: center;
}

.cta-module .cta-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cta-module .cta-wrapper .cta-content p {
  margin: 0;
}

.cta-module .cta-wrapper .cta-button {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-module">
  <div class="bottom-divider standard-spacing">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Looking for Health EFPPOS Solutions?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <div class="cta-content">
        <p>Our mobile EFTPOS facilities are convenient, portable and secure </p>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a class="button_primary" href="#">Apply</a>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a class="button_secondary" href="#">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-divider standard-spacing">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Looking for Health EFPPOS Solutions?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <div class="cta-content">
        <p>Our mobile EFTPOS facilities are convenient, portable and secure </p>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a class="button_primary" href="#">Apply</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force a line break when there is 2 buttons, you can use the `nth-last-child()` selector, which in this case will select the 3:rd element from the end, which will be the `cta-content` when there is 2 buttons, and none when there is 1 button.

And then, by simply give it a maximum width, which is less than enable the text in 1 line, it will break line, though it might look less good on wider screens.

*Based on your comment, by comment out `flex-wrap: wrap` one also prevent the buttons to never break line and position themself below the text*

```css
.cta-module {
  text-align: center;
}

.cta-module .cta-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap;         comment this out will make buttons stay 
                              side-by-side with the text                   */
}

.cta-module .cta-wrapper .cta-content {
}

.cta-module .cta-wrapper > div:nth-last-child(3) {
  _flex: 1;
  max-width: 250px
}

.cta-module .cta-wrapper .cta-content p {
  margin: 0;
}

.cta-module .cta-wrapper .cta-button {
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-module">
  <div class="bottom-divider standard-spacing">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Looking for Health EFPPOS Solutions?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <div class="cta-content">
        <p>Our mobile EFTPOS facilities are convenient, portable and secure </p>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a class="button_primary" href="#">Apply</a>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a class="button_secondary" href="#">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom-divider standard-spacing">
    <div class="cta-title">
      <h2>Looking for Health EFPPOS Solutions?</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <div class="cta-content">
        <p>Our mobile EFTPOS facilities are convenient, portable and secure </p>
      </div>
      <div class="cta-button">
        <a class="button_primary" href="#">Apply</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solutions is not working. `CTA content` should be wapped to the second line even with screen size is bigger with `cta-wrapper` has two button classes

Comment: @Arun My 3:rd sample does that.

Comment: Thanks its working for desktop. But in Ipad `cta-wrapper` with single button, `cta-button` comes in the second line.it should be aligned in the same line

Comment: @Arun So the buttons should never go into a new line?

Comment: Buttons should go to the new line only in Iphones, So If i add flex-wrap to `cta-wrapper` targeting iphone using media query

Comment: @Arun Yes, that could be an option, and with the above you have a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flex-basis` rule to define the default size of an individual flex-item.

> [**flex-basis**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis?v=control)
>
> *The flex-basis CSS property specifies the flex basis which is the initial main size of a flex item.* *...*

So in your snippet for example you could target the first child of the `cta-module` and then set the `flex-basis` for the `.cta-content` element.

```
.cta-module > div:first-child .cta-content {
  flex-basis: 220px;
}
```

This would be a very static solution though, which would only affect the first child in the `cta-module` container and it is not related to the amount of buttons inside a `cta-wrapper` element.

Another solution would be to use JavaScript to collect all `cta-wrapper` elements that contain more than one `<button>` element and then set the `flex-basis` on each `cta-content` element.

```js
const wrappers = document.querySelectorAll( '.cta-wrapper' );

const findWrapperWithMoreThanOneButton = 
wrapper => wrapper.querySelectorAll( '.cta-button' ).length > 1

const setFlexBasis =
wrapper => {
  wrapper.querySelector( '.cta-content' )
  .style
  .flexBasis = '220px'
}

Array.from( wrappers )
.filter( findWrapperWithMoreThanOneButton )
.forEach( setFlexBasis )
```

```css
.cta-module{text-align:center}.cta-module .cta-wrapper{display:flex;justify-content:center;margin:0 auto;align-items:center;flex-wrap:wrap}.cta-module>div:first-child .cta-content{flex-basis:220px}.cta-module .cta-wrapper .cta-content p{margin:0;text-align:left}.cta-module .cta-wrapper .cta-button{margin-right:1rem}
```

```html
<div class="cta-module"> <div class="bottom-divider standard-spacing"> <div class="cta-title"> <h2>Looking for Health EFPPOS Solutions?</h2> </div><div class="cta-wrapper"> <div class="cta-content"> <p>Our mobile EFTPOS facilities are convenient, portable and secure </p></div><div class="cta-button"> <a class="button_primary" href="#">Apply</a> </div><div class="cta-button"> <a class="button_secondary" href="#">Learn more</a> </div></div></div><div class="bottom-divider standard-spacing"> <div class="cta-title"> <h2>Looking for Health EFPPOS Solutions?</h2> </div><div class="cta-wrapper"> <div class="cta-content"> <p>Our mobile EFTPOS facilities are convenient, portable and secure </p></div><div class="cta-button"> <a class="button_primary" href="#">Apply</a> </div></div></div></div>
```